# error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, sockets, compiler-errors, namespaces, tcpserver

I'm creating a messaging application for andriod/ios, but I am completely new to c# and networking, I've followed the first steps of a simple socket tutorial to get me started in networking (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxdOOk6d_I0) but I get the error:

> error "CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected".

I'm assuming that it has something to do with the namespace because im new to c# and don't actually understand what the namespace does, but my compiler says there are no errors (I'm using visual studio code if that makes a difference) but it may be something else.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace server_test
{
    class program
    {
        static void main(string[] args)
        {

            IPAdress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AdressList[0];
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, 8080);
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

            try
            {
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("server started...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

it should say server started..." or throw up an exeption but this is what im getting every time:

> [Running] mono "C:\Users\Aidan\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\cs-script.user\cscs.exe" "d:!computer science!!NEA!\test stuff\networking\server_test\program.cs"
>   Error: Specified file could not be compiled.
>
> csscript.CompilerException: d:!computer science!!NEA!\test stuff\networking\server_test\program.cs(7,127): error CS1513: } expected
>   d:!computer science!!NEA!\test stuff\networking\server_test\program.cs(37,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>
> at csscript.CSExecutor.ProcessCompilingResult (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerResults results, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters compilerParams, CSScriptLibrary.ScriptParser parser, System.String scriptFileName, System.String assemblyFileName, System.String[] additionalDependencies) [0x00102] in :0 
>     at csscript.CSExecutor.Compile (System.String scriptFileName) [0x0080d] in :0 
>     at csscript.CSExecutor.ExecuteImpl () [0x005a1] in :0
>
> [Done] exited with code=1 in 1.795 seconds

Comment: IMO, you really should learn the basics (i.e. what a `namespace` is) before moving into advanced topics (i.e. networking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both answers are correct.

System.Net using was missing.
There was a typo in addresslist.

One more problem was - The main function should be spelled as "Main" with capital M.

Full program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace server_test
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, 8080);
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

            try
            {
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("server started...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, cant believe i missed that, capitalising the "main" solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

You are missing namespace import.

Add

```
using System.Net;
```

and fix the typo `AdressList` to `AddressList`

Answer (score 2):

The error shows The file could not be compiled. So, most probably it's compiler error. I guess below if it's not a typo, the spelling of ipaddress missing a d and so thus AddressList.

```
 IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
```